# Find specific cells in column N, change value in column O

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am new to VBA coding and am trying to search for a name in column N and replace the value in column O.

I have tried to modify this code but I cant get it to replace the cell next to it.

```
Columns("N").Replace What:="27", _
                            Replacement:="AARON", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

**You may use this VBA code to find value in specific Column:**

```
Columns("N:N").Select
Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="YourName", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

**And this can be used to Replace:**

```
Columns("O").Replace What:="Your Old Value", Replacement:="New Value", _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:= _
            False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

**How it works:**

- Both code can be used as `Standard Subroutine` with the Worksheet.
- Replace value to `Find & Replace` in the code as per your choice.